# when using vue-recaptcha getting some errors

Tags: vue.js

I have installed [vue-recaptcha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-recaptcha) and when I try to use `import VueRecaptcha from "vue-recaptcha";` getting this error `This dependency was not found:

- @unhead getting this after installing vue-recaptch`

Please someone hepl me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You have the vue-recacha in your package.json? If have try to clean the node_modules and install again with yarn.

But it's very simple to use

```
npm install vue-recaptcha
```

or

```
yarn add vue-recaptcha
```

import as

```
import VueRecaptcha from 'vue-recaptcha';
```

register in components:

```
export default {
  components: {
    VueRecaptcha
  }
}
```

and use like this

```
<vue-recaptcha sitekey="your-recaptcha-site-key"></vue-recaptcha>
```